# How to [cross-]compile Linux kernel with no vDSO support?

Tags: linux-kernel, llvm, sparc

I am compiling the Linux kernel for `SPARC64` [with LLVM] and I'd like to not compile the `vDSO` code. I removed all the vDSO-related arguments in `arch/sparc/Makefile`, `arch/sparc/Kbuild` and `arch/sparc/kernel/Makefile` but is there any quicker/elegant way ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HAVE_GENERIC_VDSO should be the single Kconfig setting to disable vdso.